# Obtener datos con un select y que llene los campos automáticamente (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

Tengo esta tabla, donde en el *tipo* quiero seleccionar y llamar los datos de la base de datos, y que cuando seleccione el tipo me llene los otros campos de forma automática.

[image: Taba donde incorporo un select, para que me muestre los resultados]

Código *HTML*:

```
<tbody class="t-inversiones-body">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="form-group-custom">
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm-custom" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
          <option selected value="0">Seleccionar Cliente...</option>
          @foreach ($sbu_datos as $item)
            <option value="{{$item->sbu_id}}">{{$item->abreviatura}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">Administrador del sistema</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="pre-d"><span>$</span> 585.00</td>
    <td class="pre-d"><span>$</span> 7020.00</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Lo que queres hacer es que la consulta PHP se ejecute sin tener que mandar variables por Post ni redireccionar, sino que se dibujen al seleccionar? En ese caso tenes que hacer un $("#idDelSelect).change(function(){}) y en la funcion tenes que hacer un llamado a Ajax, donde le pasas la variable del value Tipo, y ajax hara la consulta a la base de datos y retornara datos (generalmente en JSON), luego este json lo imprimes en pantalla mediante javascript.

Comment: Necesitas enviar desde tu controlador la data para llenar el tipo, posteriormente *escuchar* el evento del menu desplegable para que cuando un elemento de ahi se elija se procese una petición AJAX que traiga la data y pintes la estructura HTML con la info. requerida; por otro lado tu pregunta es amplia considera investigar al respecto y cuando tengas algo avanzado editar para saber desde que punto apoyarte

Comment: ok gracias por sus comentarios, aunque no he realizado nunca un crud con ajax, revisare vídeos para ver como se realiza eso.